# Can discord.js-selfbot fetch server members?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I know self-bots are against the TOS. This is for my understanding.
In my bot I have

```
message.guild.members.fetch();
```

Since my bot has server members intent ON, it works.

Will the same work for discord.js-selfbot?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience most things work the same. If there are any endpoints that the a user account is not allowed to access it will throw an error.